# How can I prevent access by non-staff to the `List` view action when a specific filter isn't used in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-filter

`Items` can be filtered by a `user_id` filter parameter. Only staff (`User.is_staff`) should be able to view the entire list of items. Non-staff users have to specify a `user_id` parameter to filter, or should get either no results or a permissions error (I'm not sure which would be standard practice here).

I think this could be done with a `custom permission` on the `ViewSet`, or by overriding `get_queryset` based on `user.is_staff`. In either case, I can't figure out how to base this on the `user_id` filter parameter.

Comment: how are you filtering? are you using a package like github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters or you're manually filtering by overriding the get_queryset() method?

Comment: I'm using `django-filters`, as that seems to be the one normally used with DRF, for all URL filters. I'm currently not overriding `get_queryset()` at all, but could do so for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override the list method, something like:

```
def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.request.user.is_staff and not self.request.GET.get('user_id'):
        raise PermissionDenied(detail="You must provide a user_id")
    super(MyView, self).list(*args, **kwargs)
```

[PermissionDenied](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#permissiondenied) will return a 403 Forbidden which seems ok to me

It you have the same behavior in more than one view, I'd create a [custom Permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), the code is pretty much the same.

Hope this helps